# How to edit content of aspx SharePoint page programmatically?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

There are so many page layouts with same content inside. I need to remove some of the content from these pages through c#.
For example page layouts contain:

```
<%@ Register tagprefix="xyz" namespace="abcd" assembly =abcd, version= 16.0.0.0, publickeytoken =713567888>
```

I need to remove this content from all the page layouts. Manually editing each and every page layout is very difficult. As I am not a techie , could you please help me here?

Comment: Welcome, please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to edit the Master Pages of the SharePoint sites. You can view the Master Page from

http://Sharepoint_Site_Name/_layouts/15/DesignMasterPages.aspx

You can also view them from the SharePoint Designer by opening a site and opening the "Master Pages" menu from the left hand side.